# Capture an event when windows form pages switches

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to capture event when form in windows application using c# library

when application switches its page by clicking on next button or search buttons or any other means

**Edit**

I want to capture events generated by control tabs from library.

Please refer this link,,It shows events that is generated by control tabs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please clarify why you can't just capture the button click event and do everything in that function.

Comment: i want to capture switching with library,so I want to capture all those events which leads to change in form or page

Comment: I'm not sure if you can declare a library function as an event handler, but regardless it's a lot easier to use a normal event handler and have it call the dll.

Comment: Are you developing a UWP app? Or you are developing a Windows Forms app?

Comment: I am developing library for capturing different events which leads to change in screen either by page ,window or control tabs

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to capture the `Deactivated` event of the Window.

Comment: i want to capture  switching with the help of library,so I want to capture all those events which leads to change in form or page

Comment: Does anything in the library keep a reference to a Window? As in when a window opens, does it pass a reference to itself to the library? That's how the library can register an event handler for that.

Comment: yes library is invoked from the form,,,Please see my edit in the question

Comment: Please confirm if this app is WPF, UWP or Windows Forms. The link you have provided is for Windows Forms tabs and that doesn't match the tag you have on your question.